# "tens of thousands of people" vs. "tens of thousands people"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I often confuse the two phrases.

My Google search for them has shown that the use of "*tens of thousands **of** people*" is overwhelmingly popular compared to "*tens of thousands people*".

Based on the search result, I first thought that the use of "*tens of thousands people*" was wrong, but later found [a BBC news article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-53390108) employing the two similar phrases in it as below.

> An unprecedented economic crisis in Lebanon has pushed ***tens of
> thousands people*** into poverty and triggered the largest
> anti-government protests the country has seen in more than a decade.

> ***Tens of thousands of Lebanese*** took to the streets, leading to the resignation of of Western-backed Prime Minister Saad Hariri and
> his unity government.

Are both phrases just interchangeable? If there is any difference between them?

Comment: This is a typographical error, or possibly an editorial error when wording was changed from something like *pushed over fifty thousand people into poverty* or *pushed tens of thousands into poverty*. You are correct that it should read *tens of thousands of people*.

Comment: @Jason: I used "***people***" and "***years***" for my search.

Comment: @choster: Thanks. Actually, the one I quoted from BBC is not the only example. An article from The Washington Post, for example, says "*Beef traders say the ban will make **tens of thousands people** jobless*." There are some more similar examples too. Can I just assume they are all some kind of errors?

 https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/volokh-conspiracy/wp/2015/03/06/indian-state-bans-beef-what-if-an-american-state-banned-pork-california-did-ban-horse-meat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To talk about a large number of something (in an exaggerated way), we can use the phrase :

> tens of (thousands/millions/billions) of (something).

Therefore, *"Tens of thousands of people"* is the correct phrase. *"Tens of thousands people"* is not correct.

Comment: Thanks. If that is the case, what do you think of the phrase I quoted from a BBC news article? As "choster", a commenter, commented above, do you think it is a typo?

Comment: Yes, that may be a typo.